# Why doesn't the font on my buttons change when changed in css code?

Tags: html, css, button

I need to change the font of buttons on my html site.
However, I am unable to do, for some unknown reason to me.

```css
btn-outline {
  background-color: #dff5f4;
  padding: 68px 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-outline:active,
.btn-outline:focus,
.btn-outline.active {
  background: #3c9e9a;
  border-color: #338a86;
}

.buttons_cover {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.buttons_cover a {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

button.navbar-toggler {
  float: right;
}

a.btn.btn.outline {
  font-family: robotolight;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons_cover">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline" style="border-width: 3px; border-color: #ffffff">
    <h2>X</h2>
    <p>
      <h5><i>x info</i></h5>
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="buttons_cover">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline" style="border-width: 3px; border-color: #ffffff">
    <h2>Y</h2>
    <p>
      <h5><i>y info</i></h5>
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Robotobold is definitely present.

However, the buttons do not change from the default font.

What's causing this?

Comment: You made a **typo** (voting to close the question). The `a` elements aren't members of the `outline` class. They are members of the `btn` and `btn-outline` classes.

Comment: Please learn to use headings correctly. Don't skip them (you have no `h1` and go straight from `h2` to `h5` skipping over levels 3 and 4).. Don't have headings if you don't have content associated with them either.

Comment: @Quentin: I disagree about headings. h1-h6 have default css values ready to use, no need to use all of them. But of course they should actually be headings for something.

Comment: @PoulBak — HTML is a *semantic* language. Browsers apply default styles, but elements need to be selected for their meaning not the default stylesheet. (Consider, for example, how the document would sound in a screen reader set to skim headings to find relevent content within the page).

Answer (score 0):

you must append roboto font from google at the beginning of the css and instead of robotolight you must put only roboto.
to change size you must add font-weight: 200;